# Magento 2, how to remove the order-summary in shipping-step?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, magento2, checkout

i am trying to customize the checkout of a Magento 2. At the moment, i want to change the appearance of the "shipping"-step. Can anyone give me a hint how to remove the sidebar (including the order summary)?

It should only bei visible on the "payment"-step, not in "shipping".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sidebar is added in the layout file `checkout_index_index.xml` in `magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/`.  You actually can't modify that in order to meet your requirements without extensively modding the checkout.

There is an easier solution to do it with CSS though.

Put this line to your styles: `.opc-summary-wrapper{display:none;}` and modify `magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/step-navigator.js` **do not** edit core files! Make a copy in your Theme or Module and add the following code to the function `getActiveItemIndex`

```
if (activeIndex == 1) {
  $('.opc-summary-wrapper').css("display", "block");
} 
else {
  $('.opc-summary-wrapper').css("display", "none");
}
```

Worked for me. Not my idea though,
found this answer on magento stackexchange: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229001/checkout-remove-sidebar-only-in-step-1

Answer (score 2):

Magento's docs explain how to disable an item here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html#disable

removing the summary (in this case, in mobile) is as simple as adding the following to your theme's `checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<item name="estimation" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
```

The `checkout_index_index.xml` should look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="estimation" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy

> checkout_index_index.xml

from

> PROJECT_ROOT/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout

folder and find the following line of code

```
<item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
```

then replace the lines of codes under this item block and place the following line of code

```
<item name="disbaled" xsi:type="string">true</item>
```

It will remove the order summary as well as the sidebar that contains the order summary block in shipping step of checkout page

Hope you'll find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

create `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/sidebar.html` file & make copy paste html template from `Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/sidebar.html`

```
<div id="opc-sidebar"
 data-bind="visible: canDisplaySidebarSummaryBlock(), afterRender:setModalElement, mageInit: {
'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal':{
    'type': 'custom',
    'modalClass': 'opc-sidebar opc-summary-wrapper',
    'wrapperClass': 'checkout-container',
    'parentModalClass': '_has-modal-custom',
    'responsive': true,
    'responsiveClass': 'custom-slide',
    'overlayClass': 'modal-custom-overlay',
    'buttons': []
}}">

<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('summary') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->

<div class="opc-block-shipping-information">
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('shipping-information') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->
</div>
```

then. create `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/sidebar-mixin.js`

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'ko',
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
], function (Component, ko, $, stepNavigator) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {

        /**
         * current step is #payment or not. 
         * 
         * @returns {Boolean}
         */
        canDisplaySidebarSummaryBlock: function () {
            if(stepNavigator.isProcessed('shipping')) {
                // if stepNavigator is not #shipping . then display Order Summary & remove class of width 100%
                $('.opc-summary-wrapper').css("display", "block");
                $('#checkout .opc-wrapper').removeClass('w-100');
            }else{
                $('.opc-summary-wrapper').css("display", "none");
                $('#checkout .opc-wrapper').addClass('w-100');
            }

            return stepNavigator.isProcessed('shipping');
        }
    }

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

then `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {             
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/sidebar': {
                'Microtech_Storepickup/js/view/checkout/sidebar-mixin': true
            },
        }
    }
}
```

then create `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">  
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <!-- Order Summary -->
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Microtech_Storepickup/checkout/sidebar</item>
                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                    </item>

                                    <!-- <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Microtech_Storepickup/checkout/summary</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item> -->
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```